# Java Recursion General Concept

Tags: java, recursion

Here is a simple recursion question in java. This one I have been working on but need to refine my approach.

Write a recursive method with two int parameters,  m and n. The precondition requires 0 <= m and m <= n. The method prints a line of m asterisks, then a line of m+1 asterisks, and so on up to a line of n asterisks. Then the same pattern is repeated backward: a line of n asterisks, then n-1, and so on down to n. The only loop allowed in your implementation is a loop to print a line of m asterisks.

This is what I have so far as test methods

```
package Recursion;

class Asterisk 
{
       public static void asterisk(int m, int n) 
       {
          if (m == n) 
          {
             printAsterisk(n);
             return;
          } 
          else if (m < n) 
          {
              printAsterisk(m);
              asterisk(m + 1, n);
          } 
          else 
          {
              printAsterisk(m);
              asterisk(m - 1, m);
          }
       }

      public static void printAsterisk(int m) 
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) 
          {
              System.out.print("*");
          }
              System.out.println("");
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          int m = 3;
          int n = 5;

          asterisk(m, n);
          asterisk(n, m);
      }
```

}

Comment: He's asking about help for implementing the recursion. The loop is obviously the loop the assignment is allowing him to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will work:

```
class Test {

    public static void asterisk(int m, int n) {
        if (m == n) {
            printAsterisk(m);
            return;
        } else if (m < n) {
            printAsterisk(m);
            asterisk(m + 1, n);
        } else {
            printAsterisk(m);
            asterisk(m - 1, n);
        }
    }

    public static void printAsterisk(int m) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m = 3;
        int n = 5;
        asterisk(m, n);
        asterisk(n, m);
    }

}
```

Please note that this is not the right way to do it. Since this question feels like an assignment, I will not post the accurate version. Now, your task is to remove two calls in the main method to `asterisk` and modify the method to work with a single call.

Comment: This looks like a student assignment. Try avoid giving students code, and prioritise explanations and hints over overt solutions.

Comment: @Amadan: This is not an accurate answer, I have tried to guide the OP towards coming up with an accurate recursion.

Answer (score 1):

So, you need this:

```
printAsterisk(3, 5)
***
****
*****
*****
****
***
```

Think of it this way: `printAsterisk(6, 5)` prints nothing. `printAsterisk(3, 5)` prints `3` asterisks, then inserts `printAsterisk(4, 5)`, then prints `3` asterisks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine you just need to think about what's going into `printAsterisk(int m, int n)`.

A recursive function can often be thought of as solving one small part of a repeatable problem and then delegating the rest of the problem to itself using different parameters.

Consider the following output (`printAsterisk(4, 4);`):

```
****
```

If we wanted to get the following output (`printAsterisk(3, 4);`):

```
***
****
***
```

it is easy to see that this output contains the output of `printAsterisk(4, 4);` in the middle so when you call `printAsterisk(3, 4);` it should print 3 asterisks, call `printAsterisk(4,4);` and then print the remaining 3 asterisks.

If you extend this a bit further the implementation should be easy to see.